# How set Libgdx bitmap font size?

Tags: java, libgdx, size, bitmap-fonts

I'm rendering on screen the game fps using bitmap font but there are no methods for the size. This is a problem for me because my camera viewport size is very small so the text when rendered is huge and pixelated.

```
font.draw(batch, Float.toString(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond), x, y);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Did you try setScale() method? That's what I use to resize my font.

```
myFont.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
myFont.setScale(scale);
```

If you have trouble, leave a comment.

Good Luck !!

**Edit :**

With the latest libgdx version, try to scale font like this :

```
myFont.getData().setScale();
```

Comment: note : if you want for example to reduce the size of your text to the half put : myFont.setScale(0.5f);

Comment: there is not setScale() method anymore, they removed it.

Comment: What about font.getData().setScale() ?

Comment: thanks it's still huge though even scaled at 0.5f, my viewport is just too small since I'm using box2d, so everything is in meters and not in pixel.

Comment: Implementing the above answer is not showing clean text...an method to make it clean.

Comment: Ok i got it i increased the font size while making one...but still if there is a way to do it on run time it would be helpful..

Comment: The smaller I set the scale the more letters(!?) randomly get removed, the hell

Answer (score 7):

I often use what minos23 suggested. But the downfall is that it can look pixelated especially when scaling upwards. A fancy large bitmap font can take up a lot of space and if you need many different fonts you might go over your budget.

By using [Gdx.Freetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) you are able to create bitmapfonts at runtime from small `.ttf` files. This means you only need to ship the `.ttf` files with your app and can generate a font based on user settings like resolution.

Other then scaling and the freetype solution is having multiple bitmaps of different font sizes. This way your fonts stay crisp all time but at the cost of runtime performance to generate the proper fonts.

Answer (score 3):

setScale is the function to use. Please note that with the newest LibGDX version (this changed earlier though) you need to do this isntead:

```
font.getData().setScale(2, 2);
```

before it was enough to do:

```
font.setScale(2, 2);
```

The first number in setScale is the X scale, and the second is the Y scale.

Answer (score 0):

I use setScale() function too as others to reduce the font size, but here I want to offer another solution and I have a question. Why you don't use FPSRenderer instance or why you don't draw your fps label on another batch which  projection matrix has the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Netero's answer works.
If you want to make code cleaner, you can write a helper function:

```
public static void setLineHeight(BitmapFont font, float height) {
    font.getData().setScale(height * font.getScaleY() / font.getLineHeight());
}
```